# Differentiability of addition function

Tags: calculus

A few days back I was asked this question in my class.

> **Is $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ differentiable?**

$f(x,y)=x+y$

My course of action was

$$\lim_{(\xi,\eta)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x+\xi,y+\eta)-f(x,y)}{\sqrt{\xi^2+\eta^2}}=\lim_{(\xi,\eta)\to(0,0)}\frac{\xi+\eta}{\sqrt{\xi^2+\eta^2}}$$ which does not exist.

> It is equal to $1$ if we take one of the variables $\xi$ or $\eta$ zero. (i.e. directional derivatives along the axes). If we take derivative along $x=y$, we get $\sqrt{2}$

But someone told me that I was wrong and differentiability in $\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ is determined only by the directional derivatives along the axes. Is it true? If yes, could someone explain? I am fairly new to the subject. Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like you should read the definition of differentiability in more than one variable. If your teacher follows a textbook, read the definition in that book. Otherwise, Wikipedia may be a good reference.

Answer (score 1):

If prove by definition, you should really check

$$\lim_{(\xi,\eta)\to(0,0)}\frac{f(x+\xi,y+\eta)-f(x,y)-\xi-\eta}{\sqrt{\xi^2+\eta^2}}$$

which is 0.

However you can also check whether the first partial derivatives with respect to $x,y$ are both continuous. If that's the case, it is differentiable. Also note that this is only sufficient but not a necessary condition.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, $f$ is differentiable at $(x,y)$ if, by definition, there exists a linear map $L:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $$f(x+h,y+k)=f(x,y)+L(h,k)+o(\|(h,k)\|)$$
which is equivalent to say that $$\lim_{(h,k)\to (0,0)} \dfrac{f(x+h,y+k)-f(x,y)-L(h,k)}{\|(h,k)\|}=0.$$

Since $$f(x+h,y+k)=f(x,y)+L(h,k)$$ where $L:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow \mathbb R, (h,k)\mapsto h+k$, $f$ is obviously differentiable at $(x,y)$ and its derivative is given by :
$$\begin{array}{ccc}df_{(x,y)}:&\mathbb R^2 & \rightarrow & \mathbb R \\ &(h,k) & \mapsto &  h+k\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

A function $f(x,y)$ is differentiable at $(x_0,y_0)$ if there is a limited development such as

$f(x_0+u,y_0+v)=f(x_0,y_0)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x_0,y_0)\times u+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}(x_0,y_0)\times v+\sqrt{u^2+v^2}\epsilon (u,v)$

With $\epsilon (u,v) \to 0$ for $(x,y) \to (0,0)$